# Error "void is an invalid type for the variable passwordMethod1"

Tags: java

- Discription: This program check password between 7 to 16
- characters which contain only characters, numeric digits and underscore
- and first character*/

import java.util.*;

```
public class PasswordValidationOne { 
 /**my hints on how to solve this problem
 * the length of the string must not less 7 and must not more than 16 character
 **/
public static void main (String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a password");
      String password = scan.nextLine();

      public  void  passwordMethod1( password) {
            int lengthPassword = password.length(); // getting the length of the string password
            boolean containsDigit = password.matches("*.\\d*.");
            boolean containsUnderscore = password.contains("_");
            char firstCharacter = password.charAt(0);
            if((lengthPassword >= 7&& lengthPassword<=16)&& (containsDigit == true) && (containsUnderscore == true)&& (firstCharacter >= 'A' && firstCharacter <= 'z') )
                System.out.println("Password Accepted! You can proceed");
            else
                System.out.println("Password not accepted! Retry");
      } //end of method passwordMethod1()

}// end of main method
```

}//end of the class

Comment: `\\d*` will match **none**, one or more digits; some special characters between `A` and `z` (e.g. `[` or `^`)

Comment: Seriously! are you defining a method inside main() method?

Comment: i' m just starting out majuran

Answer (score 2):

The error is correct, if a bit misleading (apparently). This

```
public  void  passwordMethod1( password) {
```

is missing the **type** for **`password`**, you wanted

```
public  void  passwordMethod1(String password) {
```

Also you cannot declare a method inside another method (move that block outside `main`).

Comment: and it would be better to return a boolean value indicating whether it has passed or not

Comment: oh year thanks the main problem is that i declared a method in side a method

Comment: After moving the method outside of main, you need to make the method static to call it from main. (public **static** void passwordMethod1(String password))

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `( String password)` Correct your method parameter

From

```
public  void  passwordMethod1( password) {
            int lengthPassword = password.length(); // getting the length of the string password
            boolean containsDigit = password.matches("*.\\d*.");
            boolean containsUnderscore = password.contains("_");
            char firstCharacter = password.charAt(0);
            if((lengthPassword >= 7&& lengthPassword<=16)&& (containsDigit == true) && (containsUnderscore == true)&& (firstCharacter >= 'A' && firstCharacter <= 'z') )
                System.out.println("Password Accepted! You can proceed");
            else
                System.out.println("Password not accepted! Retry");
      }
```

To

```
public  void  passwordMethod1( String password) {
            int lengthPassword = password.length(); // getting the length of the string password
            boolean containsDigit = password.matches("*.\\d*.");
            boolean containsUnderscore = password.contains("_");
            char firstCharacter = password.charAt(0);
            if((lengthPassword >= 7&& lengthPassword<=16)&& (containsDigit == true) && (containsUnderscore == true)&& (firstCharacter >= 'A' && firstCharacter <= 'z') )
                System.out.println("Password Accepted! You can proceed");
            else
                System.out.println("Password not accepted! Retry");
      }
```

Lastly add the **passwordMethod1** method **outside** from `Main` method.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the datatype of password in the function declaration.

Try using

```
public void passwordMethod1(String password) {
```

Instead of

```
public void passwordMethod1(password) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the `passwordMethod1` inside the `main` method, that's not valid. The compiler expects a variable there, hence the error message.

Move it outside.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a password");
      String password = scan.nextLine();

      passwordMethod1( password);

}// end of main method

public  void  passwordMethod1(String password) {
    int lengthPassword = password.length(); // getting the length of the string password
    boolean containsDigit = password.matches("*.\\d*.");
                boolean containsUnderscore = password.contains("_");
    char firstCharacter = password.charAt(0);
    if((lengthPassword >= 7&& lengthPassword<=16)&& (containsDigit == true) && (containsUnderscore == true)&& (firstCharacter >= 'A' && firstCharacter <= 'z') )
        System.out.println("Password Accepted! You can proceed");
    else
        System.out.println("Password not accepted! Retry");
} //end of method passwordMethod1()
```